# List of objects

Tags: php, regex, string

what is the best method to find the parent items of a comma separated string?

e.g.

```
array(1,2,3),array("test","123, abc"),1,"abc, 123"
```

to get

```
array(1,2,3)
array("test","123, abc")
1
"abc, 123"
```

Is this possible to get with a regular expression, or is there a nifty php function that will do this?

Comment: I'm assuming the first bit of code is an array.

Comment: correct, so once I eval it it will be a PHP array, but I just want to get the parts for now.

Comment: So if the first part is actually `$my_array = array(array(1,2,3),...);` you need to tear this apart?

Comment: oh hey that might actually work, I could eval it with array(...) around it, good idea!

Comment: Avoid eval() if you can at all help it. It leads easily to security bugs.

Comment: Agreed, thats a nasty path to go down. I'm also not sure you are familiar with how php handles its data types. What is the goal usage of this data?

Comment: I know how PHP handles it's data types, working on a pretty large project, I was hoping to find a solution with a regular expression, well aware of not wanting to use eval, that's why I hinted at regex.

Comment: looks like I'm still looking for a way to parse the string into strings but only the parts that are objects, such as arrays, objects, strings, numbers etc.  I went as far to do an eval on the string, but if I have a variable I cannot get the value of that variable as it's not in scope.

Answer (score 0):

Use `explode`.

```
$myarray = explode(",",$original);
```

This is assuming that your original is a string, and your desired output is something you can easily iterate through:

```
$original = 'array(1,2,3),array("test","123, abc"),1,"abc, 123"';
$myarray = explode(",",$original);
foreach ($myarray as $item) {
  echo $item."\n";
}
```

Comment: Explode works on strings. So given the first data is just a string this would in fact be part of the answer.

Comment: @CP510 I'm not sure what you're driving at?

Comment: He seems to be creating a multi-dimensional array, not a string.

Comment: that will split the string up by comma, but not at the right parts as the group array(1,2,3) would also be split, I want to get the parent groups.

Comment: Good point; not sure what to tell you, other than this strongly suggests a design problem further upstream.

Comment: actually this will help my project out substantially, and will make things much easier in the future.  It's a secret though maybe one day you'll see the project.  For now I can only secretly ask obscure questions.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
$arr = array(array(1,2,3),array("test","123, abc"),1,"abc, 123");
$newarray = array_chunk($arr, count($arr));
print_r($newarray);
```